# react componentDidMount is called executing after render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new to React JS and I am now puzzled by the way how component life cycle methods work; which is entirely in contradiction with ReactJS.org docs in my case. The componentDidMount() should execute before render() is what the expected behaviour, but render() executes before componentDidMount().

My source code :

```
import React from 'react';
import '../main.css';
//import sam from "../images/gallery/Farmer1.jpg";
import galleries from './GalleryImages.js';
class Gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  cache = {};
  dummy = './Farmer1.jpg';
  importAll = (r, ping) => {
    console.log(ping + ' called');
    r.keys().forEach(key => {
      this.cache[key] = r(key);
      console.log(`key is ${key} and value : ${r(key)}`);
      this.dummy = r(key);
    });
    console.log(this.cache);
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.importAll(
      require.context('../images/gallery/', false, /\.jpg$/),
      'mount'
    );
  }
  render() {
    //this.importAll(require.context('../images/gallery/', false, /\.jpg$/),"render");
    console.log(this.cache);
    const gallery = galleries.map(gallery => {
      return (
        <a
          className="spotlight"
          href={gallery.src}
          data-title={gallery.title}
          data-description={gallery.description}
        >
          {console.log(this.cache[gallery.src])}
          <img src={this.cache[gallery.src]} />
        </a>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="container margintop150">
        <div className="greentext center">
          <h4>
            {' '}
            <b>Gallery</b>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <h5 className="type_5" />
        <div className="row">
          <div
            className="spotlight-group"
            data-title="Untitled"
            data-animation="fade"
            data-fullscreen="false"
            data-maximize="false"
            data-minimize="false"
          >
            {gallery}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Gallery;
```

```
//GalleryImages.js
const galleries = [
  {
    src: './Farmer2.jpg',
    title: 'Farmer2',
    description: 'farmer2'
  },
  {
    src: './Farmer1.jpg',
    title: 'Farmer1',
    description: 'farmer1'
  },
  {
    src: './Farmer3.jpg',
    title: 'Farmer3',
    description: 'farmer3'
  }
];
export default galleries;
```

the class variable this.cache is `null` if `this.importAll()` is called in `componentDidMount()`, but it takes up the values if `this.importAll()` is called in `render()`.

[image]

Comment: `componentDidMount()` executes after first `render()` call. You may refer [this](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) diagram to get better understanding of how lifecycle goes

Comment: just think about it for a second. compoent **DID** mount. Meaning it **DID** already mount, which would mean the render function would have to run for it to be mounted (you can already see it in the browser). So yes it should be after the render, but only on the mounting render. Not after subsequent rerenders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood lifecycle in react js.

`componentDidMount` will be called after `render` is called at the first time.

For more information: [The component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

Answer (score 3):

It's the right behavior, componentDidMount() is called after render.

> These methods are called in the following order when an 
>   instance of a component is being created and inserted into 
>   the DOM:
>   
>  * constructor()
>   
>  * static getDerivedStateFromProps()
>   
>  * render()
>   
>  * componentDidMount()

The deprecated componentWillMount() is called before.

> Note:
>   These methods are considered legacy and you should avoid 
>   them in new code:
>
> UNSAFE_componentWillMount()

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing `componentWillMount()` with `componentDidMount()`. `componentWillMount()` is called before the render while calling `setState()` in `componentDidMount()` can re-render the component

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your answer might better written as a comment under the original question. I think there might be something similar already there.  Answers are reserved for *complete* explanations to a user's question.  Good job for responding though!